# Prolog - finding the product of a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm super new to prolog (swi prolog) so sorry if this is a dumb question. Also this is a uni assignment. I was asked to find the product of a list and this is what I came up with:

```
product([],1).
product([H|T], Product) :-
    product( T, Product1),
    Product is H * Product1.
```

For the longest I had the base case as:

```
product([],0).
```

But that makes everything zero. However, when testing the base case of
`product([],Product)`, I get one - which is incorrect. Any hints to a solution will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it is incorrect. The identity element of reals or integers under multiplication is indeed 1.

Comment: I agree with Boris: `product([], 1)` should be the correct base case due to 1 being the multiplicative identity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not incorrect: 1 is the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) of "numbers" under multiplication. You can for example abstract away the operation, and the loop, to have something along the lines of:

```
list_op_product(L, Op, P) :-
    identity_element(Op, IE),
    reverse(L, R), % no foldr in SWI-Prolog, at least
    foldl(Op, R, IE, P).
```

So you only need to define `identity_element/2` and the operation itself. So, addition and multiplication would be something like:

```
identity_element(add, 0).
identity_element(mult, 1).

add(X, Y, R) :- R is X + Y.
mult(X, Y, R) :- R is X * Y.
```

And then you can say:

```
?- list_op_product([2,3,4], add, Sum).
Sum = 9.

?- list_op_product([2,3,4], mult, Product).
Product = 24.
```

Similarly, the identity element of string concatenation is the empty string. So, if you just add the following clause to `identity_element/2`:

```
identity_element(atom_concat, '').
```

You can now say:

```
?- list_op_product([a,b,c], atom_concat, R).
R = abc.
```

Of course, most of this is unnecessary, but it shows the point.

As for the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33647328/1812457): there is maybe a cleaner way than a cut to avoid incorrect answers:

```
product([], 0).
product([H|T], P) :-
    product_1(T, H, P).

product_1([], P, P).
product_1([H|T], H0, P) :-
    product_1(T, H, P0),
    P is P0 * H0.
```

So now:

```
?- product([2,3,5], P).
P = 30.

?- product([], P).
P = 0.
```

But this feels wrong. You should still have a base case:

```
product([], 1).
```

This clause of `product/2` simply defines what your identity element is; this is why it is still better to leave the 1 there and not replace it with a 0! However, you will do one multiplication less for non-empty lists (you won't have the last `* 1`). This is a valid and easy-to-make optimization. If you try to find the product of a type that does not have an identity element at all: then, `product([], X)` is not defined. You can either leave out the clause, then `?- product([], X)` will fail. Or, you can maybe throw an error?

Comment: Typo in your first sentence: *...of "numbers" under addition* should be *...of "numbers" under multiplication*. I agree (+1): the base case should be `product([], 1)` because of 1 being multiplicative identity, for the same reason that `sum([], 0)` would be a base case for sum.

Comment: @lurker not a typo, a thinko. Thank you!

Comment: The name `list_op_product/3` no longer fits the general predicate very well, since the predicate denotes the *sum* instead of the *product*, depending on the parameter. Also, it is natural to perform multiplications like `a*b*c` as `(a*b)*c`, so a fold from the left is in fact a good fit for this case. A fold from the right corresponds to `a*(b*c)`, which is not how `*/2` associates naturally nor in Prolog.

Comment: @mat Concerning the naming, I was left with the impression that "product" is the generic name of applying an operation (usually denoted with the circle). Am I wrong about this?

Comment: @Boris, I know, that's why I did not state: "The name `list_op_product/3` does not fit *at all*." ;-) It just does not fit very well in the case for `sum`.

Comment: @mat as for the left or right fold, it doesn't matter when the operation is commutative, but it does matter when it is not: for example, string concatenation. Using a `reverse` plus a right fold just made it easier to emulate the non-tail recursive original code shown in the question. But I am still not sure: does subtraction for example have an identity element? Does it at all make sense to try and say `?- list_op_product(L, subtract, Result).`?

Comment: Yes, I also noticed the point about conatenation. My prefernce in such cases is to swap the arguments in the auxiliary goal, like: `ac(A, B, C):- atom_concat(B, A, C).` and then use a fold from the left over the auxiliary goal. Subtraction, antisocially, has a right-identity, but no left-identity, so to generalize this further, you would have to distinguish the different properties (commutative or not, left- or right identity etc.).

Comment: @mat Ok, everything you say makes sense. On my endless (and probably misguided) quest for knowledge, I have been trying to read a book co-written by Alex Stepanov (of C++ STL fame). The way he deals with those issues (using C++) is to indeed define algorithms that depend on what operation are defined for the particular type passed to them. For example, you cannot raise an element of a semigroup to the power of 0, etc (for concrete example, see `power_semigroup(a, n, op)` [defined here](http://www.fm2gp.com/code/ch07.h).

Comment: Reading anything by Alex Stepanov is definitely a good way to approach such issues! There are also some great talks by him on Youtube.

Answer (score 4):

As often when describing relations involving lists, it makes sense to start with describing two cases: One for the empty list, and one for lists involving at least one element.

In the second clause, you can use `foldl/4` and a small auxiliary predicate. For example:

```
list_product([], 1).
list_product([L|Ls], P) :-
        foldl(product_, Ls, L, P).

product_(A, B, P) :- P is A*B.
```

And in fact you can equivalently write this as:

```
list_product(Ls, P) :- foldl(product_, Ls, 1, P).
```

The product of the empty list is sensibly defined as 1 so that, when building the product over several lists, empty lists blend in naturally and do not change any results.

Examples:

```
?- list_product([1,2,3,4], P).
P = 24.
```

and:

```
?- maplist(list_product, [[1,2],[],[3,4]], Ps), list_product(Ps, P).
P = 24,
Ps = [2, 1, 12].
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree to the viewpoint expressed by @Boris, but I think that if you want 0 as a result for an empty lists, you could exploit *pattern matching*, one of distinctive features of Prlog:

```
product([], 0).
product([N], N).
product([H|T], Product) :-
    product(T, Product1),
    Product is H * Product1.
```

Since the base case introduced overlaps with the recursive clause, a cut is needed, to avoid

```
?- product([2,3,5],X).
X = 30 ;
X = 0.
```

So please change my suggestion as required.

*edit* to avoid the cut, an alternative pattern could be

```
product([], 0).
product([N], N).
product([H,I|T], Product) :-
        product([I|T], Product1),
        Product is H * Product1.
```

now second and third clauses don't overlap anymore, but could be that your Prolog isn't smart enough to optimize the predicate...

Comment: Good answer, but see the addition to my answer for a straight-forward way of avoiding the cut (of course you knew that already).

Comment: Although this kind of efficiency is rarely an issue in a language like Prolog, I'd guess. The reason why I showed this code is because it does not have a cut and is not too much of an overkill (as the fold is).

Comment: I think the fact that a cut is needed to avoid an incorrect answer for `X` underscores the fact that the base case should be `product([], 1)` since 1 is the multiplicative identity. In mathematics, the identity element is, in some sense, the default when there is nothing. So you have facts such as `a = a x 1 x 1 x ... x 1` for any number of 1's, as I can keep operating with identities without changing the value. In other words, when nothing is there, the identity (1) is assumed. Maybe `product([], X)` could fail, but `X = 0` is the wrong answer, imho.

Comment: @lurker: this is getting complicated... but since 0 will be the outcome of any sequence having at least a 0 (iirc, 0 it's called the absorbent element, or something like this) why to rule out it for a particular case ? I think the usefulness depends on use... and here we have a uni assignment, and we don't know the original problem statement

Comment: I don't think it's complicated. :) Think of it this way. If I have list L1 with product p1, and list L2 with product p2, then I append the lists as L3, what should the product of L3 be? I would suggest it should be p1 x p2. But if the product of the empty list is 0, it wouldn't work. A fact `product([], 0).` creates both a logical and mathematical discontinuity.

Comment: @lurker: I don't get your point... my own simply takes OP' *requirement*: it states 'which is incorrect'. That's all...

Comment: The OP said they don't *think* it is correct, meaning they aren't sure. The answer should describe what's correct.

Comment: Sorry you're right. I misread. But I still think the answer should show a correct answer. The fact that their asking means there are some doubts.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that the product of an empty list should be 1.

First reason, as CapelliC's answer shows, if you require it to be 0, then you have a logical discontinuity. The predicate needs special handling to deal with a 0 product versus a 1.

There's no special reason for the product of an empty list to be 0. The fact:

```
foo([], X).
```

Describes a relation `foo` between `[]` and `X`. What should `X` be? Just because the list is empty doesn't mean that the logical answer is `0`.

Let's look at another perspective. Suppose I have two lists of numbers,`L1` and `L2`. And suppose the products of these lists are `p1` and`p2`, respectively. Then if I have:

```
append(L1, L2, L), product(L, X).
```

What should `X` be? I would think it would be `p1 x p2`. If `L1 = [2, 3]` and `L2 = [4, 5]`, then we have `p1 = 6`, `p2 = 20`. `L = [2, 3, 4, 5]`, whose product is 120, which is `6 x 20`. So far so good.

Now suppose `L2 = []`. Then `L = [2, 3]`. If `product(L2, 0)`, then I'd have `p2 = 0`, and `p1 x p2 = 0`. But `product(L, 6).` so the logic breaks down and we have mathematical or logical discontinuity. However, if `product([], 1).`, then this all works as expected.

In an arithmetic sense, algebraic identity is what you have by default if there is nothing. For sums, the identity is 0, and I can write `a` as `a + 0 + ... + 0` and still have `a`. Likewise, `a` can be written `a x 1 x ... x 1`. So it makes mathematical sense for `product([], 1).` to be true.

Comment: +1! The empty product is sensibly defined as 1 for the same reason that 0 is sensibly defined as the *sum* of the empty list: Both denote the respective identity element. Defining the product of the empty list to be 0 makes about as much sense as defining the sum of the empty list to be 134.