# Prolog multiply all elements of a list

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I want to define a predicate in Prolog, prod_list/2 that multiplies every element of a list. I'm having problem with the empty list wish the product should be zero, instead i get false. 
My code is

```
prod_list([H], H).
prod_list([H|T], Product) :- prod_list(T, Rest), 
                            Product is H * Rest.
```

The results I get are 
prod_list([4,3],Product). -> Product = 12
but when I do prod_list([], Product). I get false instead of Product = 0.

Please help.

Comment: You have a clause for a list  with one element, add a clause for the empty list.

Comment: Why do you think product of `[]` should be `0`? See this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645947/prolog-finding-the-product-of-a-list/33651745#33651745).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that *no* clause matches the empty list. In fact you have a recursive clause:

```
prod_list([H|T], Product) :- prod_list(T, Rest), 
                        Product is H * Rest.
```

but its recursion terminates when there is only an element in the list:

```
prod_list([H], H).
```

So, in no case the empty list `[]` is matched by a clause, and for this reason, the answer is `false` (no match available).

To solve your problem you need to include an explicit clause for the empty list:

```
prod_list([],0).
prod_list([H],H).
prod_list([H|T], Product) :- prod_list(T, Rest), Product is H * Rest.
```

A different solution could be found considering that the product of an empty list should be (correctly) defined in this way:

```
product_of_list([], 1).
product_of_list([H|T], Product) :- product_of_list(T, Rest), Product is H * Rest
```

then you could add your “special” definition of `prod_list`:

```
prod_list([],0).
prod_list(List, Product) :- product_of_list(List, Product).
```

**Edit**

The last solution does not work for some interactive versions of Prolog (for instance Swish on-line), while it *does* work for [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.11). A solutions that should work for every version is the following:

```
prod_list([],0).
prod_list([H|T], Product) :- product_of_list([H|T], Product).
```

Thanks to user474491 for discovering this.

Comment: I would think that the last solution would return 2 results for the empty list : 0 and 1.

Comment: @user474491, if you try it you will find that it returns only the value 0.

Comment: I just tried on Swish on-line, and I do get 2 results for prod_list([],Result), as expected.

Comment: I tried it on [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org), (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.11), and it gives only one result. Maybe different semantics?

Comment: Since it is better to have a solution that always works, I have updated the answer. Thanks @user474491 for reporting the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Renzo's answer is perfect. I just thought of functional treatment of lists when I saw your question. You can have them just in case you need them. If you define a function multiplication:

```
mul(V1,V2,R) :- R is V1*V2;
```

then you can use foldl in any of its variants:

```
?- foldl(mul, [1,2,10], 1, R).
R = 20 .
```

`fold` is a traditional functional calculation function that applies a function accumulating the temporal result.

Comment: Or `foldl(\V1^V2^R^ (R is V1*V2), [1,2,10], 1, Rx).`

Comment: Of course, but this needs the lambda module, right?